# Display full images in carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have three images to be kept in carousel. I am facing a few problems here.

1) In the desktop version, the images are stretched out to the width of carousel and the height as well. But I am not getting the full image in that height (please check the code link).

2) In the mobile version, the images have not filled the height of the carousel.
The menu in the navbar is appearing behind carousel.

Code: http://jsbin.com/pivehekula/edit?html,output

CSS code:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  .img {
height:35px;
margin-right:2px;
}
.navbar-brand {
position:relative;
bottom:5px;
color:white;
}
.menubar {
margin-right:90px;
}
.navcolor {
background-color:#A30000;
height:75px;
padding-top:10px;
}
#colour a,#colour1 a{
color:white;
}
#colour a:hover {
background-color: #FF3D3D;
}
#colour1 a{
color:white;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
#navb {
background-color:#A30000;
}
#colour a{
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.slid {
height:500px;
position: relative;
bottom:16px;
}
.carousel-inner{
height:500px;
}
.carousel img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 500px;
max-width: none;
}
```

Body:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navcolor">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" id="colour1">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand" class="pull-left" >
            Uprising Rivals
            </a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"  id="navb">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menubar" id="colour">
<li><a href="TYR.htm">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="form.htm">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#com">Community</a></li>
<li><a href="">Strategies</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide slid" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="http://p1.pichost.me/i/13/1359503.jpg" class="har">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://all4desktop.com/data_images/1920%20x%201200/4211692-abstract-color-background-picture-8016.jpg"  class="har">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.macwallhd.com/wp-content/Wallpapers/Abstract/Mac%20Wallpaper%20Spin%20The%20Apple%20Circle-575024442.jpeg" alt="cont" class="har">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to paste snippets from your code here in case folks do not want or are unable to access your pastebin.

Comment: @Nathan, Thanks for responding to my question. I dont know where I went wrong(please check the 2 points in question).As u said, I have put the code here.Hope you will answer my question.Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all you need to do is stipulate a height for the carousel-inner, Then a height of 100% for the carousel-inner item, Then a height for the carousel-inner item img.  It should look like the following:

```
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner{
  height: 500px;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .item{
  height: 100%;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with that working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/2whuq8g8/)

The only thing about this is it will stretch the image in ways that will look unpleasing so you may want to create a background image to each of the items in the carousel so the images will look normal.

So what you may want to do is get rid of the images in carousel and give the carousel item a padding-bottom of a certain percentage and play with this percentage untill your carousel is the desired height that you want.  Then give each item a background image like so:

```
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .item{
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .first-item{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://p1.pichost.me/i/13/1359503.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .second-item{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://all4desktop.com/data_images/1920%20x%201200/4211692-abstract-color-background-picture-8016.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .third-item{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.macwallhd.com/wp-content/Wallpapers/Abstract/Mac%20Wallpaper%20Spin%20The%20Apple%20Circle-575024442.jpeg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And just add the class to each item in the carousel like:

```
<div class="item active first-item">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item second-item">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item third-item">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be responsive and not skew your images and make them look weird.

Here is a working fiddle for that [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/x684ne7y/)

As far as the navbar goes give the navbar a postion and a z-index to make sure that it is above the carousel like:

```
.navbar-default{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```